# Как разбить строку на три подстроки по определенному правилу? (Используя Java regex)

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Пишу простенький чат и решил заодно попробовать разобраться с java regex. Потратив пару часов и не придя к результату, понял, что что-то делаю не так. Я попытался разбить строку на 3 части по определенному правилу. Например: есть строка "/w имя_получателя какое-то сообщение любой длинны" при разбитии её на подстроки должно получится "/w", "Пользователь", "какое-то сообщение любой длинны". На этом месте пока затык, буду рад Вашей помощь. Желательно подробно объяснить, как это делать чтобы я получил представление как разбивать строки regex в дальнейшем.

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String message = "/w herename some message is here";
       sendMessage(message.split(" ")[1], message); /*вместо message регулярное выражение 
которое пропускает первые два слова "/w herename".
/w неизменна и всегда находится в начале сообщения,
herename может быть любым с любыми символами, но это всегда одного слово.*/

    }

    public static void sendMessage(String from, String message) {
        System.out.println(from + " whisper you: " + message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: @Kromster спасибо за уточнение, исправил вопрос с учетом Ваших подсказок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Регулярные выражения это просто. С помощью них мы описываем шаблон, применяемый для поиска строки в тексте. Для описания шаблона нужно знать синтаксис регулярных выражений. Например знак `\w` означает последовательность букв, цифр и знака подчеркивания, `.` любой символ, квантификатор `+` задает количество символов 1 и более для поиска, а квантификатор `?` после другого квантификатора говорит о том, что поиск ленивый и будет останавливаться при первом совпадении.

Соответственно `/w herename some message is here` переводим в шаблон: `/w .+? (.+)` и через `Matcher` вытаскиваем содержимое `(.+)`:

```
String text = "/w herename some message is here";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/w .+? (.+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил просто ограничив число разбития строк с помощью split(" ", 3).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String message = "/w herename  zdv zxcvxzvc zxcvzxcv zxcvvzxcv zxcvzxxzv asD  dfsg sdf gsdfzzfdome message is here";
        sendMessage(message.split(" ")[1], message.split(" ", 3)[2]); /*вместо message регулярное выражение
которое пропускает первые два слова "/w herename".
/w неизменна и всегда находится в начале сообщения,
herename может быть любым с любыми символами, но это всегда одного слово.*/

    }

    public static void sendMessage(String from, String message) {
        System.out.println(from + " whisper you: " + message);
    }
```